# phpfileuploader post uploader object with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I used script of http://phpfileuploader.com/

I need post uploader object to another php file with jquery but not worked :

for example I used this code :

```
var uploaderobject= document.getElementById("myuploader");
    $.post("example.php",{ sampleobject:uploaderobject},function(data)
   {
     alert(data); // but not worked or return empty result.
   })
```

Now how can use sampleobject in example.php and how can use of phpfileuploader methods for example (FileName,FileSize,FileGuid,FilePath or CopyTo,MoveTo,Delete) ?

I used this code in example.php but not worked :

```
<?php
$uploader=$_POST["sampleobject"];
echo $uploader->FileName; // not worked why ?
// or how can use myuploader methods here?
?>
```

Comment: It's `getElementById` not `getelementbyid` and why are you posting a `HTMLElement` object?

Comment: i edited that but my probelm not is about document.getElementById

Comment: i want use of methods of uploader in example.php

Comment: I haven't used that PHP library but you are doing something fundamentally wrong in here, read it's documentation again.

Comment: Hey @undefined i dont want uploader plugin i want slove this code

Comment: I read documents of phpfileuploader complete and i can see a example to used post uploader object in self page but i can not find any example to used in seperate page .

Comment: i am waiting for answers,please help me,my problem not sloved yet .

Answer (score 0):

PHP wont get an object out of a POST request, to see what you are getting out of that request use this:

```
<?php
 echo '<pre>POST REQUEST:';
 var_dump[$_POST];
 echo '<br/><br/>FILES ARRAY:';
 var_dump[$_FILES];
```

Both $_POST and $_FILES are arrays. Use `$_FILES` if you are uploading files, later on you can move the temp file to a another hard disk location.